# What the Nginx Control panel?

Tags: nginx, control-panel

What the Nginx Control panel?

What the Nginx Control panel?

and Free

thanks

Comment: Are you looking for something like cPanel but for nginx?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a list of popular and free alternatives for cP and some of which work on nginx. http://www.squidoo.com/10-free-cpanel-alternatives

Webmin for Nginx is in development here: http://github.com/vixh/nginx-webmin

Hope this helps.